# How do I find my Outpost(s)?

Tags: starfield

In my adventures I found a planet that had an iron deposit, which I need a lot of. I placed down the outpost marker, miner, and powered up. Then I went on my way with other interstellar adventures... I've been gone for a while, and travelled all over, so the miners probably need to be emptied.

But, I have no recollection what star/planet the Outpost is actually on... It doesn't show up in the outpost crew menu. How can I find this outpost? Do I just need to select random star systems and planets and hope to find it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have an outpost on a planet in a given star system, this symbol will appear by the system's star on the galactic map:

[image: screenshot of map icon indicating outpost]

That same icon is present over the planet or moon where your outpost is, when you click down into the star system's map. In the following screenshot, I have an outpost on Kapteyn I.

[image: screenshot of system with icon over a planet]

There can be multiple icons if there are multiple things in a given system. I have an outpost in Alpha Centauri. You probably know that this is also the system where Jemison (the capital of the United Colonies) is located. So both icons show on the galactic map:

[image: screenshot of alpha centauri with outpost and faction icons]

Things get a bit noisy here in the solar system map, but you can see the colony icon on the left-most moon, Zamka, in the following screenshot:

[image: screenshot of alpha centauri]

Comment: Are you sure? I have not built one single outpost yet, but I see your symbol from the first screenshot near many planets that I have visited.

Comment: Did you discover an existing facility on that planet? Perhaps the symbol also represents structures on the planet

Comment: @Neon1024 Yes, I have discovered facilities (and sometimes caves) on such planets.

Comment: This symbol on the galactic map will always indicate your outposts. On the solar system map, it may also indicate facilities but I've not seen it yet personally.